# search a pattern in file and output each pattern result in its own file using awk, sed

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I have a file of numbers in each new line:
$cat test

```
700320947
700509217
701113187
701435748
701435889
701667717
701668467
702119126
702306577
702914910
```

that I want to search details of from another larger file with several comma separated fields and out put results in

```
700320947.csv
700509217.csv
701113187.csv
701435748.csv
701435889.csv
701667717.csv
701668467.csv
702119126.csv
702306577.csv
702914910.csv
```

Logic:

```
ls test | while read file; do zgrep $line *large*file*gz >> $line.csv ; done
```

Please assist.
Thanks

Comment: Why is this tagged with `sed` and `awk`? Which shell are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since nothing said about the structure of the large file, I'll just assume that the numbers in test are to be found in the second column of the large file; generalize as needed.

This can be done in a single pass through each of the files by using output redirection in awk:

```
awk -F"," 'FILENAME == "test" { num[$1]=1; next } 
  num[$2] { print > $2".csv" }' test bigfile
```

Comment: Hi! The test numbers are to be found on the 14th field of the large file.

Answer (score 3):

Unzip the large file first; using zgrep means unzipping on-the-fly for *every* line of the number file... very inefficient. After unzipping the big file, this will do it:

```
for number in `cat test`; do grep $number bigfile > $number.csv; done
```

#### Edited:

To limit hits to whole words only (eg `702119126` won't match `1702119126`), add word boundaries to the regex:

```
for number in `cat test`; do grep \\b$number\\b bigfile > $number.csv; done
```

Comment: That means as many reads of the *large* file as there are lines in *test* (10? 1000?) .. and what if longer(larger) numbers in *large file* contain the tested number, eg. testing for an undelimited  *702119126* will also output lines containing *1702119126*

Comment: Thanks Bohemian.The large files are large and many. However, this has worked. Thanks!

Comment: fered, "testing for an undelimited 702119126 will also output lines containing 1702119126" this is acceptable.

Comment: @bernie see edited answer for how to limit hits to whole words

Comment: Yes, that is a corollary. My point was that the question says the bigFile contains *comma separated fields*, but come to think of it, even that is open to conjecture.. Are the numbers being tested for only part of the field? Only *bernie* knows :)